# How to step frames in a movie recorded by iPhone

Tags: iphone

Is there a way to have my iPhone program step frame by frame through a movie recorded by the iPhone? What I want to do is have the user record a quicktime movie, then be able to step through the movie frame by frame.

Alternately, I suppose if there was a way to extract every single frame from the movie to a jpg, then I could easily step through the pictures. Anyone know of a way to do this???

I suppose the third option (which might not get past Apple's store) is to capture the movie the way the old jailbroken apps did, which is somehow capture the pictures directly from the camera view????

Any help appreciated. Thanks in advance!!!!

Answer (score 1):

You cannot step through a movie frame by frame. That functionality does not exist in the public API.

You can include your own media decoder code (open source or not) and use that to parse your movies of course. It is perfectly fine to do that.